# iPhone-App Doesn't play 3GP Video After Apple Update

Tags: iphone, video, 3gp

I have a problem with my iPhone app. I will try my best to describe it.

1. I have an iPhone app that can display a web page.
2. This webpage has a link to a 3GP video.
3. Clicking on this link will open the video and play it.

This was working for a long time, but after a recent Apple Update, i got the message:

> "Can't play this file"

Here is a Firefox screenshot from the file.
[image: MIME-Type]

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what could have changed?

Thanks!

*edit: added Screenshot*

Answer (score 1):

See this SO answer: [iPhone UIWebview video playback 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016481/iphone-uiwebview-video-playback-4-0/3117596#3117596)

The answer (and its comment) is about MIME type settings of the server. If the MIME types are not set correctly by the webserver, the playback might fail.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
I made a screenshot (see first post). Looks to me that the MIME-Type is set correctly, or did i miss something?

Comment: Probably the feature was removed from iOS. In docs it says: _The video technologies in iOS support the playback of movie files with the .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and **.3gp** filename extensions and using the following compression standards:..._ (standards are H.264 and MPEG-4 video with some restrictions see [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) ). On the [specs page](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html) there is not mention of 3gp... So it might just not work any longer.

Comment: Thanks @marcus. I will try a .mp4 file and post results.